# Simple stereo mixer for multiple computers

Tags: mixing

I'm not planning on doing any actual recording or anything, but I have two computers, an iPod and a DAB radio that all output stereo sound, and I'd like to pipe them all into my Creative 5.1 PC speaker system. I can make do if I only get basic stereo (i.e. front L/R).

What kind of mixer do I want? Obviously I'm not looking to spend a lot. I quite think the [ART Splitmix4](http://www.artproaudio.com/products.asp?type=90&cat=13&id=155) will do what I want (variable for a few inputs mixing to two outputs - front and rear) but I'm not totally sure. Is there any specific type of mixer I should be searching for?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I've answered the question since I know an answer, but it's not clear if this question would fit better on another SE site. There's [a meta discussion about questions like these](http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/questions/204/are-non-production-video-and-audio-questions-on-topic-here) going on right now if you want to weigh in.

Answer (score 1):

Mixers just mix audio sources. Any mixer with enough line-level stereo channels and the proper kind of inputs (1/4" or XLR or RCA or whatever - probably 1/4" for computers) ought to do the trick. The one you linked should work fine.

Depending on how you have your home system set up, some kind of home theater receiver may also work (maybe you already have one that sums signals?), but that's beyond both the scope of this site and my own knowledge.